# How to append a row in a xml using groovy

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I have this xml where i'd like to add a new `row`

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <name>Abhishek</name>
    <host>abhishek123@cjb.net</host>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>Simon</name>
    <host>a@a.com</host>
  </row>
<rows>
```

I used MarkupBuilder(writer) to create this xml but now how can i append a new `row` element

**Edited**:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in Groovy, one solution is:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def xml = """<rows>
  <row>
    <name>Abhishek</name>
    <host>abhishek123@cjb.net</host>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>Simon</name>
    <host>a@a.com</host>
  </row>
</rows>"""

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )
root.appendNode {
  row {
    name( 'tim' )
    host( 'a@woo.com' )
  }
}

def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String result = outputBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield root }
```

Comment: @abhishek [mkp is a special namespace used to escape away from the normal building mode of the builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/xml/StreamingMarkupBuilder.html) and get access to helper markup methods 'yield', 'pi', 'comment', 'out', 'namespaces', 'xmlDeclaration' and 'yieldUnescaped'. [Examples here](http://www.groovyexamples.org/2010/06/22/mix-tags-and-text-using-a-markupbuilder/)

Comment: I tried it thanks, so result gets all the xml but then how is it going to get persisted in the same file? I edited my question to show how am i getting the xml

Comment: @abhishek Just write the string back out to the file? `new File( 'a.xml' ).setText( result )`  **WARNING** If you are using to the file for persistence (as I suspect) -- especially from a web-service -- the chances of it getting screwed up due to multi-threading issues and race conditions are **MASSIVE**.  Please consider using some sort of database, and write a servlet or something to generate the XML when requested by a user from the records in the database...