# How do I read an XML file using XmlSlurper and insert in tree built with MarkupBuilder?

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm writing a script that generates an XML document using MarkupBuilder and I'd like to insert an XML file in the tree read from a file. How do I do that? An example is below.

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
builder.root() {
  new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("file.xml"))
}
```

I tried mkp.yield and mkp.yieldUnescaped but both result in escaped text appearing in the output. A post on the Groovy mailing list seems to suggest that this is possible with StreamingMarkupBuilder but it's not clear if a solution exists for MarkupBuilder.

Comment: I see bunch of examples and answers to your questions and any questions related to CRUD operations except the D-Delete in the following link. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See @Tim's answer for appending node to existing tree:
[How to append a row in a xml using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198154/how-to-append-a-row-in-a-xml-using-groovy)

Not tested, but this should get escaped output:

```
def(xml,build,output)
xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( new File("file.xml").getText() )
build = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
output = build.bind{ mkp.yieldUnescaped xml }
```

Comment: +1 and `xml = new XmlSlurper().parse( new File("file.xml") )` might be cleaner :)

Comment: I tried that solution and it does work however it does not answer the question asked: is it possible to insert an XML document using MarkupBuilder?

Comment: If we use XmlSlurper to change the contents of the xml as above, how can we then write those changes to the same file we initially parsed the xml from? Because in my gradle.build, if I do `new File("file.xml").write(output)`, file.xml doesn't actually change!?

Comment: Use `new FileWriter("file.xml") << build.bind{ mkp.yieldUnescaped xml }`